# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [French Language Stack Exchange](http://french.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://french.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Difference between “réveiller” and “éveiller”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8091/difference-between-reveiller-and-eveiller)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Comment formuler l'équivalent de « any two of three things » en français ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/comment-formuler-lequivalent-de-any-two-of-three-things-en-francais)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Comment parler des décennies ? — How to refer to decades verbally ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8070/comment-parler-des-decennies-how-to-refer-to-decades-verbally)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Informal first person plural object](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8057/informal-first-person-plural-object)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Traduction de « equate the components/entries » dans un contexte mathématique](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8199/traduction-de-equate-the-components-entries-dans-un-contexte-mathematique)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [« Seul » et « seulement » : quelle est la différence ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8122/seul-et-seulement-quelle-est-la-difference)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Que signifie « chacun à notre tour » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8201/que-signifie-chacun-a-notre-tour)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Complément de temps qualifiant une action infréquente, mais pas un état infréquent](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8036/complement-de-temps-qualifiant-une-action-infrequente-mais-pas-un-etat-infreque)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Qui s'enfuit, déjà, dans la chanson de Jacques Brel ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8035/qui-senfuit-deja-dans-la-chanson-de-jacques-brel)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Quelle traduction imagée pour « a baker's dozen » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8024/quelle-traduction-imagee-pour-a-bakers-dozen)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 3)

---